# could have been vs. could be

Tags: modal-verbs

In a grammar book, I read

> We use *could* (not *can*) plus the perfect when we speculate about the possibility of an earlier event.

An example from the same book:

> With better communication, the battle could have been avoided and the lives of more than 2000 people could have been saved.

I was wondering what happens if "could have been avoided" is replaced with "could be avoided" and "could have been saved" is replaced with "could be saved". I guess that such changes don't make the sentence ungrammatical. But how is its meaning affected?

Comment: In this case, the sentences would switch to talking about the future.

Comment: @Esther, Here is an example from the book which uses _could_ and according to the book is talking about possibility in the past: "The old house could be quite cold, even in summer."

Comment: that sentence is not speculative at all